# xbee communication for Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use an Xbee series 1 pro to communicate from an arduino to a laptop.  I was planning on using the `rosserial_xbee` but the stack was removed from the metapackage.  Is there anyway to use the xbee for communication?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59046/xbee-communication-for-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was recently fixed.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3